# Ensuring lowest latency neighbors in peer-to-peer network for nodes on the internet

Tags: blockchain, p2p, bittorrent, dht, peer

How do I ensure in a peer-to-peer network that each node's neighbors are the ones with least latency? Are there any systems currently in production that do that? e.g. Bittorrent, blockchains

If I were to use a DHT, are there some techniques used in current systems to make sure each node's neighbors are closest in network hops or latency?

Comment: There are many approaches and research papers on this topic. Can you narrow down the question, maybe by adding your underlying motivation? What are you trying to optimize for?

Answer (score 1):

In an unmonitored decentralized (permissionless) environment. that would be almost impossible. most modern p2p networks are based on [Small world networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network) which means a peer is connected to a small limited number of neighbors. it uses the connections with these peers to spread messages or lookup data in the network. since all peers are connected in such a network there should be a path that connects every peer in the network.

You could try using heuristics like message latency to just drop peers and connect new peers or let other new peers connect you. but apart from your own heuristic about the peers you know, you can't know which peers are "the best" for you.

Also in a decentralized setting, this would reduce the randomness of the network and might increase attack vectors like [eclipse attacks](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61151/eclipse-attack-vs-sybil-attack).

In a **distributed** (and not permissionless) environment. (data centers, distributed databases, etc..) this could be achieved more easily since you can monitor and control all of the nodes without worrying for an adversary. 
Edit: and yes in a distributed setup DHTs indeed can be used to reduce network latency or hops for spreading a message or looking up data.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ensure in a peer-to-peer network that each node's neighbors
>   are the ones with least latency?

There are a few tricks, outlined in the paper: [Sub-second lookups on a large-scale Kademlia-based overlay](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6038665) (full text version [here](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:436670/FULLTEXT01.pdf)).

In short:

1. have an affinity for peers with low response times. To prefer adding those in your routing table, potentially replacing existing nodes with higher response times.
2. have an affinity to "spread out" the node IDs in your routing table buckets. If everyone does that, you can get 3 bits closer to your target per round-trip, rather than the 1 bit.
3. Have the routing table buckets closer to the "top" (covering half, a quarter, an eighth etc) be larger than 8. iirc, the paper suggests 128, 64, 32, 16 for the top buckets. This can also shave off a few bits from the search, saving round-trips.

> Are there any systems currently in
>   production that do that? e.g. Bittorrent, blockchains

Yes, at least libtorrent and uTorrent implements these. I would expect other bittorrent clients do to.

> If I were to use a DHT, are there some techniques used in current
>   systems to make sure each node's neighbors are closest in network hops
>   or latency?

Network hops; not that I know of. Latency; yes. bittorrent.